# Knockout mapping plugin options

Tags: knockout.js, mapping, observable

I'm not sure how to instruct the plugin to make not observable a specific property of an inner array.

Take this JSON as my data:

```
{
    Id: 1,
    Description: "test",
    Roles: [{ Id: 1, Name: "Role 1" }, { Id: 2, Name: "Role 2" }]
}
```

The Roles array should be observable, but I don't want to make observable the "Id" fields for any of the items, I'm trying differents approaches, but with no luck:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, { 'copy': [ "Roles.Id" ] });
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, { 'copy': [ "Roles[].Id" ] });
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, { 'copy': [ "Roles[0].Id" ] }); // this only works with the first item
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a direct solution for your problem, I tried to navigate to the descendants of `Roles` array but none working(like your tries) but you can make simple trick by defining your model for `Roles` item object:

```
function RolesModel(id, name) {
    this.Id = id;
    this.Name = ko.observable(name);
}
```

Then use the mapping configuration to control the creation of your `Roles` object like this :

```
var mapping = {
    'Roles': {
        create: function (options) {
            return new RolesModel(options.data.Id, options.data.Name)
        }
    }
}
```

as i told you i don't know direct solution but this gonna work. Kindly check my **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ebram/L2XLX/)**

Answer (score 1):

Ok, maybe I found the solution, starting from the @ebram tharwat suggest.

I've splitted the mapping options in two:

```
var mappingRole = { 'copy': ["Id"] };

var mapping = {
    'Roles': {
        create: function (opts) {
            return ko.mapping.fromJS(opts.data, mappingRole);
        }
    }
};
```

and then my original mapping could be something like:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
```

and seems to work fine, not sure about performance, but to me is more important to not have to define manually the descendant viewmodels.